# checkboxes in forms, unable to fetch the value posted in drupal

Tags: drupal, drupal-modules

```
$langoptions = array(1=>'German',2=>'English',3=>'Spanish',4=>'French',5=>'Portuguese',6=>'Chinese',7=>'Italian',8=>'Japanese');

       $form['language'] = array(
        '#type' => 'checkboxes',
        '#title' => 'Language',
        '#multiple'=> TRUE,  
        '#options'=> $langoptions,  
      );
```

Created a list of check box like this and in callback I tried to access it as

```
foreach ($_POST['language'] as $key => $value) {
    echo $value;
}
```

and it does not display any value, can any one help me in fixing this?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using standard form API, the postdata should be in $form_state['values'] at hook_submit().

Just to be sure -- have you checked any of the checkboxes prior to submitting?  They will only be sent in POST if checked.

Comment: What kind of callback exactly? The submit callback? See http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--form.inc/group/form_api/7 for how you should be doing form handling in Drupal. A Hint: You never use $_POST ;)

Comment: @Berdir: while submitting I load the result in ajax, so I did not use hook_submit(), instead I call another path and that path has a callback function where I access my form element, pls see my code here,  $form['submit'] = array ('#type' => 'image_button', '#val' =>t('Submit'),'#src' => 'sites/all/themes/ncomputing/images/success_search.jpg','#ahah' => array('path' => 'suc_stories/getresult','wrapper' => 'success_stories_result','method' => 'replace','effect' => 'fade',),); in /getresult under hook_menu $items['suc_stories/getresult'] = array('page callback' => 'suc_stories_result_callback',

Comment: Yes I have checked the form and when I use a trace tool (like smart sniff to see what is posted) it shows language[1]=1&language[5]=5 in the post but it also shows language= empty. Like language[1]=1&language[5]=5&language=&name=Jaya, this is not done with standard form api, I am using the form with drupal_get_form in my module for a search function which requires criteria selected from this checkboxes, in my callback function I tried to fetch value as $_POST['language']